# Seeing no perspective in job - low motivation

Tags: career-development, developer, motivation

I'm currently working as a consultant in the it department of an company which is active in industry. I've studied computer science and my goal was to become a software developer. My job currently consists of developing, database (MS SQL), installation and support of our application. And being an interface between our internal it systems and external programmers and consultants. My developing is done in c# for an update program of our application and improving our application we deliver to customers. This is a proprietary IDE and language.

My problem is now since we are not an software company, we shift to give the development to external companies. Earlier I've maintained a CRM, but this will now replaced and it will customized by the external creator.

What makes me sad is that most of the current developments I do in our application are only small functions or is only bug fixing. For example only changing a GUI or changing a existing class or methods. But I don't really add new things into our appliaction. The bigger exentions does the external company, because they do it faster since it's their product. Since it's proprietary there is no help in the internet available.

I don’t get more opportunities to do things which help me to learn more - the direction goes more to outsourcing the development to external companies. This is sometimes a way for me to learn something about development and database from the external consultants but this happens very rarely.

The other point is that I don't want to do that much support of installing and handling our program. Which consumes still a lot of time in my daily business.

I've also gently mentioned my concerns to the team leaders, but they don't seem that much interested in putting effort in training when they can have it faster from external companies.

My other problem is: at the moment I’m not in a good mood but I don’t know if it is because of my working situation or not. And currently I completely lack of motivation and lack of motivation to drag me out. And I’m not sure how to change and what exactly is the reason (working situation? Does a job change solve the problem?). Maybe anyone was in a similar situation or has some advice?

Comment: I am confused. The product you are talking about: is the product is owned by your company or is it a third party product you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer :

this is only a personal, subjective answer. Your situation, and the way you ask question, make possible to give advice, but no real answers.

### TLDR : Quit this job before it consumes you for a better suited one

From what you said, you are unhappy at work.

You seem to like development, but it's only a small part of your job. There is a lot of job available as software developer, so you can definitely consider seriously to be a full-time developer.

You also said in your question :

> I've also gently mentioned my concerns to the team leaders, but they don't seem that much interested in putting effort in training when they can have it faster from external companies.

This means that you can't really expect the situation to change.

As your current job is not adapted to you, and as software development is a developing sector, once again, it's time to move for a better job.

**That does not mean your current company is bad : they have some needs, you have yours, and they are incompatible. Just find a company with compatible needs.**

> My other problem is: at the moment I’m not in a good mood but I don’t know if it is because of my working situation or not. And currently I completely lack of motivation and lack of motivation to drag me out. And I’m not sure how to change and what exactly is the reason (working situation? Does a job change solve the problem?). Maybe anyone was in a similar situation or has some advice?

That's another problem, much more personal, so I can only give personal advice.

I can't tell you if your bad mood is caused by your job, or if changing it will really help. Even for you, it's hard. You will probably know it only few years after, with hindsight.

Can a job make you feel bad ? Yes. Is *your* job making *you* feel bad ? maybe.

Will changing the job will make you happy ? Hard to say, but I guess it wont hurt you.

From personal experience, changing environment can really help. but if your depression is deeper than only your job, don't expect to be the holy solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a job change solve the problem?

It *can*.  Right now, reading the tea leaves a bit here, it seems your job is transitioning to or is fully a maintenance role.  These roles are not necessarily bad, and its difficult to find a *pure developer*, but it is not hard for a talented developer to find a role that is more of a blend of the two.  (Maintenance and New Development.)

If you decide to pursue a new career opportunities, make very sure that you ask questions in that regard. (New coding *versus* maintenance)

> Maybe anyone was in a similar situation or has some advice?

I have indeed been in that situation before.  The way I got out of pure maintenance coding early in my career was to work with more modern technologies **on my own time**.  I would make small projects, that were all mine and not a previous employers, that I could use to demonstrate my skills.

On a slightly different note, I find the exercise helps my mental well being.  YMMV.